# Excel distinct count (ignored blanks) with date criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

```
ColA   ColB
CODE   DATE
AAA    2020-11-04
AAA    2020-11-04
BBB    2020-11-04
       2020-11-04
BBB    2020-11-05
BBB    2020-11-05
```

I have this excel table in sheet1
I want the following distinct count in sheet 2

```
ColA         ColB
Date         Dist_Count
2020-11-04   3  <== this should be 2
2020-11-05   1
```

following array formula is running on sheet2 colb , but my formula kept counting "BLANKS" as well, how do I avoid this? Or are there any more simple formula to do this task?

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2=sheet1!B:B, COUNTIF(sheet1!A:A, "<"&sheet1!A:A), ""), (COUNTIF(sheet1!A:A, "<"&sheet1!A:A)))>0))
```

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: @Harun24HR I am using office365 excel, probably excel 2020

Comment: I'd use an pivot-table to be honest

Comment: @JvdV could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Select your data, insert pivot table, but make sure to click "add data to the data model". It's pretty straightforward from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Office365` then try-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$7,($B$2:$B$7=D2)*($A$2:$A$7<>""))))
```

[image]

To refer another sheet just use sheet name before ranges.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=D2)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7<>""))))
```

> ***Edit:*** Non `Office365` formula.

Try below array formula-

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9=A2,IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9<>"",MATCH("~"&Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9&"",0))),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1),1))
```

You must Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

Comment: unfortunately, my excel doesn't recognize FILTER() :(

Comment: @ZawLynnHtut Oh! Please check my edited answer and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 3 things that I would like to clarify..
1. the last bit of your second formula, "-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1" is it suppose to be sheet1!A2 ? Not, sheet1!A2:A9 ?
2. When I was testing out , my excel says "Excel run out of resources..." error
3. my excel is office365 but IT dept nvr bothers to update the build. Mine is only v1801. That's why I don't have filter()

Comment: @ZawLynnHtut You can omit that `-Row(...)+1`. Just use `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9=A2,IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9<>"",MATCH("~"&Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9&"",0))),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)),1))` That is not for sheet reference means not sheet1. Frequency formula `bins_array` use same height of `data_array` to make this same we used `Row(....)+1` in my other project and copy paste it. So you can remove it in your case.